# Do frames start to display during the end of the previous frame or during the beginning of the next frame?

Tags: display

If one frame is transitioning to another frame, and a monitor has a 4 ms response time, does that 4 ms transition happen at the end of the first frame so that the next frame displays on time, or does it start its 4 ms transition whenever the next frame is meant to be displayed? I see response time brought up in regards to causing the image to trail or ghost, but I was wondering if a 4 ms response time would cause someone to react to a frame 4 ms slower.

[image]

*[Image source](https://i.rtings.com/images/articles/20-80-response-new.png).*

I'm not sure because rtings has graphs on response time that show the transition begin before 0, which I assume means the time when the frame is meant to be displayed. The image is from their article *[Our TV Motion Tests
Response Time](https://www.rtings.com/tv/tests/motion/motion-blur-and-response-time).*

Comment: A bit more context please.  Exactly what sort of display are you referring to as they may not be all the same.

Comment: A monitor, specifically a VA monitor.

Comment: Response time is the delay between when the pixel starts to update and when the pixel reaches some set fraction (usually 90%) of its final value.  During that time it shows intermediate values between the initial and final color.  If the response time is speced as 4 ms, then you would wait  4ms after the transition begins to see the pixel reach (most of) its final color/intensity.

Comment: I've inlined the image (rather than have your readers have to follow a link). Can you [edit] your post and add a credit to the article for context?

Comment: Thanks, I've done so

Answer (score 0):

The response time is how long a pixel value takes to actually change, so it is the time from the moment when it is set to a new target value to actually reach 90% of the new target value due to the response time of the display.

Comment: And this doesn't start early to compensate for response time? Because I was looking at how rtings measures response time, https://i.rtings.com/images/articles/20-80-response-new.png , and I noticed that the transitions would start before 0. They didn't define 0, so I was thinking it was supposed to be when the frame was supposed to display, meaning the transitions starts early.

Comment: A frame starts when it starts and each pixel you see gets its own turn to get a new value. Then the pixels takes the time it needs to slowly transition to the new value. There is no mechanism to get an early warning about a change.

Comment: @Mechrast Frames are streamed to a display in real time as they are generated. "Starting early" would mean showing a frame before it arrived, which is not possible. T=0 in your plot is the time when the pixel first reaches the target value (the green line).

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense. Additionally, I know that color is irrelevant to the response time, just how dark or light the color is. But if it take 10 ms for the transition from a dark blue to a light red, do you know how quickly it turns from blue to red? I imagine this happens at the refresh rate of the monitor